# SQL (& Laravel): getting the latest row of each group with condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this data in db:

```
id | user_id | status
1  | 7 | sent
2  | 7 | pending
3  | 8 | pending
4  | 8 | sent
```

how do I make a query so that I get this result:

```
id | user_id | status
4  | 8 | sent
```

this query is not working as expected:
`MyTable::where('status', 'sent')->groupBy('user_id')->get();`

result:

```
id | user_id | status
1  | 7 | sent
4  | 8 | sent
```

the latest `status` in db on `user_id` of `7` is `pending` and I don't want to include it in the result.

please help

fyi, I'm using Laravel 9. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved:

```php
$rawQuery = "(SELECT MAX(my_tables.id) AS max_id FROM my_tables GROUP BY my_tables.user_id) AS latest";

MyTable::->join(
 DB::raw($rawQuery),
 function ($join) {
  $join->on('my_tables.id', '=', 'my_tables.max_id');
 })
 ->where('status', 'sent')
 ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should select only the last status where it is 'sent'

somethink like:

```
$result = Users::whereIn('id', function ($query) {
    $query->selectRaw('MAX(id)')
        ->from('users')
        ->groupBy('user_id')
        ->havingRaw("MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'sent' THEN id END) = MAX(id)");
})
->where('status', 'sent')
->get();
```

I did not got the change to test it.